# iPhone : Get the file path which is within subfolder of Resource folder

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, file, path, nsbundle

I am new to iPhone programming. I want to read the content of a text file located in a subfolder of the Resource folder.

The Resource folder structure is the following:

Resource

1. Folder1---->Data.txt
2. Folder2---->Data.txt
3. Folder3---->Folder1---->Data.txt

There are multiple files named "Data.txt", so how can I access the files in each folder? I know how to read the text file, but if the Resource structure is similar to the above structure then how can I get the path?

For example, if I want to access the "Data.txt" file from Folder3, how can I get the file path?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To continue psychotiks answer a full example would look like this:

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *filePath = nil;

if (filePath = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"Folder1"])  {

    theContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    // when completed, it is the developer's responsibility to release theContents

}
```

Notice that you can use -pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory to access ressources in sub directories.

Comment: But there are multiple Folder with same Name in different folder. so in this case how can achieve the path

Comment: @Rupesh: For the second folder you would need to use: `[thisBundle pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"Folder3/Folder1"]`. Notice that `inDirectory:` argument is relative to the bundle root.

Comment: You should really use `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]`, this way the memory is _"managed"_, and more importantly `initWithContentsOfFile:` is deprecated since Mac OS X 10.4, and **not available on iPhone OS**. So the code will only work in simulator.

Comment: @Peylow - I agree with you.
The example is a modified version from the NSBundle documentation which does not use autorelase pools.

Comment: @PeyloW - While initWithContentsOfURL is indeed deprecated, Apple did so merely to require you to specify an encoding (wise move on their part). So the method initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error: is available in iOS 2.0 and later (at least through iOS 5.1).

Comment: What if I want to retrieve all files in the folder, this doesn't seem to work....     NSString *inWorkPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"In-Work"];
    NSArray *resContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:inWorkPath error:&error];

Answer (score 16):

Your *"resource folder"* is actually the contents of your main bundle, also know as the application bundle. You use `pathForResource:ofType:` or `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` to get the full path for a resource.

Loading the contents of a file as a string is done with the `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` method for an autoreleased string of with `initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:` if you want a retained string.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" 
                                                     ofType:@"txt"
                                                inDirectory:@"Folder1"];
if (filePath != nil) {
  theContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                             error:NULL];
  // Do stuff to theContents
}
```

This is almost the same answer as given by Shirkrin previously, but with the slight difference  that it works on target. This is because `initWithContentsOfFile:` is deprecated on Mac OS X, and not available at all iPhone OS.

Answer (score 8):

[Shirkrin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1496460/1367622) and [PeyloW's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1496932/1367622) above were both useful, and I managed to use `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` to access files with the same name in different folders in my app bundle.

I also found an alternative solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581681/1367622) that suited my requirements slightly better, so I thought I'd share it. In particular, see [this link](http://majicjungle.com/blog/123/).

For example, say I have the following Folder References (blue icons, Groups are yellow):

[image]

Then I can access the image files like this:

```
NSString * filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pin_images/1/2.jpg"];
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

As a side note, the `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` equivalent looks like this:

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"pin_images/1/"];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString* path = [bundle bundlePath];
```

This gives you the path to your bundle. From there on, you can navigate your folder structure.