# contentOfFile path gives null

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2, filepath

I'm trying to get all the text from a txt file into a string, but if I try to NSlog() this string, i get null. I think it's because of the path i'm trying to get the file at, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with the path. I know that i get the right navigationItem.title, so that is not the problem. The text file is in the main bundle in a subfolder called Øvelser/Text/"nameOfExercise".txt. I have pasted my code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//Read from the exercise document
NSString *path = [[@"Øvelser/Text/" stringByAppendingString:self.navigationItem.title] stringByAppendingString:@".txt"];

if(path)
{

    _exerciseDocument = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", _exerciseDocument);
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"error");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NSBundle` methods to get paths relative to the bundle.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496373/iphone-get-the-file-path-which-is-within-subfolder-of-resourse-folder) is similar and gives this as a way of creating the path:

```
NSBundle *thisBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *filePath = nil;

if (filePath = [thisBundle pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"txt" inDirectory:@"Folder1"])  {

    theContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    // when completed, it is the developer's responsibility to release theContents
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nil back because something is going wrong reading the file.  If you pass a pointer to an error object, it will get filled in with error details and that will tell you what is going wrong if you log it.  Don't ignore error information.

```
NSError* error = nil;
 _exerciseDocument = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path 
                                               encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding  
                                                  error: &error];
if (_exerciseDocument == nil)
{
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
else
{
     // success
}
```

NSString has lots of lovely methods for manipulating paths and you should use them.  In particular construct your paths by using [stringByAppendingPAthComponents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathComponent_) and [stringByAppendingPathExtension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-stringByAppendingPathExtension_).