# iPhone trying to use NSSTring class to save a string to file

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to use the `stringWithString:` and `stringWithContentsOfFile` to save a string to a file and then read it back.  It seemed like it should be very simple, but the object return by `stringWithContentsOfFile` is a `null`

code

```
// test strings
NSString *s=[ NSString stringWithString:@"hi"];
[ s writeToFile:@"test.txt" atomically:TRUE];

NSString *g=[ NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"test.txt"];
```

Comment: Could you try with an absolute path for your test.txt file? Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979321/contentoffile-path-gives-null

Comment: First off, `stringWithString` is pointless unless your source string is mutable and you want a non-mutable version.  You could simply say `NSString* s = @"hi";`.

Comment: Next you need to figure out what your "current directory" is. Likely it's the "bundle", which is read-only.  So you should specify a target directory explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, it will try to save the test.txt file in the root directory, and we can't have access to the root directory. The only way to save a file is to write it on the application document directory :

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.txt", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]];
[s writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Comment: also note that `writeToFile:(NSString *) atomically:(BOOL)` is deprecated in favour of `writeToFile:(NSString *) atomically:(BOOL) encoding:(NSStringEncoding) error:(NSError **)` in iOS 6

Comment: You completely right, I edited my answer.