# Need a little help in loading image with absolute path

Tags: ios, uiimageview, imageview, imagenamed

I have 400 images with repeating names, hierarchically divided among folders which i have included in my project, now i want to load images with the absolute path, I tried using `imagenamed` but instead of images being load, empty box is showed. Now I need a little help in how can i show images using absolute path.

Hierarchy of my project

```
Project
     -> Project Files (i-e App Deligate and view controllers)
     -> Resources
            ->Images
                  ->1
                      ->1.jpg
                      ->2.jpg
                      ->3.jpg
                  ->2
                      ->1.jpg
                      ->2.jpg
                      ->3.jpg
```

Method i am using to load images

```
[self.leftImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Images/1/1.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and so on... Any one, help.
Regards

Comment: You cannot use same named images in XCode project. Because at the build creation, XCode creates a single folder (aka main bundle) to store all its resources. It doesnot refer to manually created folders (like 1, 2 in your example). So over there same named images gets replaced.
Use separate names to all image files.

Comment: @mrunal i have 400 images, so i can't rename them all ? can you suggest me a solution to fetch the image using absolute path or something like that ?

Comment: Sorry but its rule set by apple itself. For better way, download some file rename manager and rename all those files. 
In your code, you might require to change by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your Comments

The following method may help you

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)ext inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath;
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)ext inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath forLocalization:(NSString *)localizationName;

- (NSArray *)pathsForResourcesOfType:(NSString *)ext inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath;
- (NSArray *)pathsForResourcesOfType:(NSString *)ext inDirectory:(NSString *)subpath forLocalization:(NSString *)localizationName;
```

You can try this code

```
NSString * sample=[[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] ofType:@".jpg" inDirectory:@"foldername"];
[self.leftImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:sample] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And also you cant have 2 images of same name. You will get a duplicate symbols warning while building ur app.

For memory efficient use pathforresource type rather than image named for UIImage because it will have some cache memory on ViewControllers.

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: i am not getting any warning at all, i have different folders not different groups ?

Comment: Yello color, as i told you i am using folders not groups.

Comment: Well i think i should change the image names, as per apples guidelines :) by the way thanks for your help and time. Regards

Comment: @X-Factor  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496373/iphone-get-the-file-path-which-is-within-subfolder-of-resourse-folder

Comment: I am selecting it as answser :) Thanks