# can't get UIImage's init(contentsOfFile:) to work

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I am trying to locate a file in a subdirectory of subdirectory of my bundle. I used this code to create an UIImage with `init(contentsOfFile:)`.

```
let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "Level1")      
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: resource!)
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This works because groups you create in xcode editor do not affect the actual path.

```
let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: nil)
```

or `let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg")`

Comment: unable to get the resource. so pass a proper path . right click on the 1g.jpg and show in finder and then paste the path  after the project name in the "inDirectory: ????" ? mark position

Comment: My complete path: file:///Users/user/Desktop/MattNeuburg/pathFinder/pathFinder/1g.jpg I tried pathFinder/1g.jpg, pathFinder, pathFinder/pathFinder. None worked:/

Comment: would you share your project via dropbox or something so i can take a look?

Comment: just figured it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are get the error **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**, this means **your variable is set to nil, but your code is expecting it to not be nil.**

do like check the resource contains value or not.

*let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "Level1")* 
  *print (resource)*  //

then

do like

**Choice -1**

```
if let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "Level1") 

{
  let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: resource!)
}
else
 {
 print (resource)
 }
```

**Choice -2**

```
let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "Level1")      

if resource != nil {
//Do Something
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: resource!)
}
```

for additional [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496373/iphone-get-the-file-path-which-is-within-subfolder-of-resource-folder)

Comment: @krompir2 -- your coding is correct, check once your directory is correct or not , I given the reference link check once , you get some idea

Comment: I checked the link and nope, it still wont work. I also used this approach: let resource2 = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType).pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg", inDirectory: "CustomAssets/Level1/")

Comment: ya correct , but not get the answer , ok do like initially check all subdirectories and then put the above lines

Comment: look like groups havee no effect on actual path

Comment: ha ha, Ok in your update question where.in which line get the error

Comment: then in your update question you show like **This is screenshot of my bundle and also the error I am getting:** , this means

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Based on the path Fatti Khan mentioned I tried

```
let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg",inDirectory: nil)
```

which is the same as

```
let resource = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1g", ofType: "jpg")
```

It seems that even though I created groups in xcode editor that had no effect no the actual path, which is:  `file:///Users/user/Desktop/MattNeuburg/pathFinder/pathFinder/1g.jpg`. pathFinder is the name of the project.